# KeyboardAvoidingView not working with TabNavigator

Tags: react-native

I have component in tabnavigator. In my component I have text multiple line so I want use KeyboardAvoidingView to push screen when keyboard show, when I enter multiple line in InputText keyboard over it.
Here is my code:

```html
class UselessTextInput extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                {...this.props} // Inherit any props passed to it; e.g., multiline, numberOfLines below
                editable={true}
                autoFocus={false}
                placeholder={Const.TEXT_INPUT_DELETE_ACCOUNT}
                //maxLength={10000} 
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

```html
class SettingProfileDetail extends React.Component {
render(){
 return (

            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.textTitle}>
                    {Const.REASONDELETEACCOUNT}
                </Text>
                <UselessTextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    multiline={true}
                    numberOfLines={1}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ reason: text })}
                    value={this.state.reason}
                />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView >

        );
}
}
```

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    textTitle: {
        fontFamily: font.bold,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#666666',
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 18
    },
    textInput: {
        fontFamily: font.normal,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        padding: 0
    },
});
```

and here is my result:
[image]

It only happen when I add code in component on TabNavigator, when add in App.js it work fine
How I can fix my bug?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, though I had a different approach that basically will calculate and positioning (using translateY) the view when the keyboard appears.

I have published it here, visit [react-native-spacer](https://github.com/hieunc229/react-native-spacer) for more default

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and took inspiration from @Hieu Jack Nguyen. Still clunky but a bit better.

You can see bellow my SO question (with videos and issues) and in the comments a link to my Gist where I copied my current implementation.

[React Native - Android - keyboardavoidingView in stackNavigator within a tabNavigator pushes bottomTabBar (clunky behaviour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856752/react-native-android-keyboardavoidingview-in-stacknavigator-within-a-tabnavi)